# dont find ldap library for apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redhat, ldap

I am trying to configure Apache version 2.4.27 and enable ldap. I also install this library without error:

```
./config --prefix=/opt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f shared

make depend, make, make install

CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f/include" LDFLAGS="-Lopt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f/lib" ./configure --prefix=/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45 --disable-slapd --with-tls=openssl

make depend, make, make install


./configure --prefix=/opt/lib/curl-7.54.1 --with-ssl=/opt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f

make, make install

./configure --prefix=/opt/lib/pcre-8.41

make, make install       

./configure CFLAGS=-DXML_POOR_ENTROPY --prefix=/opt/lib/expat-2.2.2

make, make install
```

Below is the command for configuring httpd -2.4.27:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd-2.4.27 --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/opt/lib/pcre-8.41/ --with-ssl=/opt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f --enable-so --with-expat=/opt/lib/expat-2.2.2 --enable-suexec --with-openssl=/opt/lib/openssl-1.1.0f --with-ldap-include=/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45/include --with-ldap-lib=/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45/lib --with-crypto --with-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap
```

I put the APR(1.6.2) APR-util(1.6.0) files in the srclib directory. During the ./configure I have the following error:

```
checking for ldap support...
  adding "-I/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45/include" to APRUTIL_INCLUDES
  adding "-L/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45/lib" to APRUTIL_LDFLAGS
checking for ldap_init in -lldap50... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapssl41... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapssl40... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapssl30... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapssl20... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapsdk... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldapsdk... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldap... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldap... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldap... no
checking for ldap_init in -lldap... no
configure: error: could not find an LDAP library
configure failed for srclib/apr-util
```

without LDAP I don't have any errors.

any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you also need openldap-devel package.

Comment: I tried the source, but I could not find it, because I do not want to install it through rpm. Do you know if there is also the source file of the package?Thx

Comment: What's in `/opt/lib/openldap-2.4.45/lib`?  What symbols do those files contain?

Comment: I found the problem, did not take openssl library dependencies. just export the library: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/ opt / lib / openssl-1.1.0f / lib /"
Thx all for support

Comment: If you found the problem and fixed it, please write that in the "Answer" box below and then accept the answer. That might help someone else having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, did not take openssl library dependencies. just export the library: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/ opt / lib / openssl-1.1.0f / lib /"

Thx all for support